# Robolectric and Mockito testing for Android FSM app

Tags: java, android, mockito, robolectric, fsm

I wrote a simple Android FSM app like described [here](http://www.questioningsoftware.com/2007/03/finite-state-machines.html).

And I need to test it with *Robolectric* and *Mockito* in *Android Studio*. 
 I've installed these plugins and read all the documentation, but have no idea how to test `if()` method using these frameworks.

Could you please advise, how I can do it?

The simplified example of my code in MainActivity.java is the next:

```
boolean stateOne = true;
boolean stateTwo = false;

public void onClickmethod_for_button (View view) {
    if (stateOne) {
        stateOne = false;
        stateTwo = true;
    }
    if (stateTwo) {
        stateTwo = false;
        stateOne = true;
    }
    displayState()
}

private void displayState() {
    final TextView stateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_state);
    String stateText;
    if (stateOne) {
        stateText = "State is one";
    } else {
        stateText = "State is two";
    } 
    stateTextView.setText(stateText);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sure, thanks for your point.